# How to check if is a custom product type option in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created custom product type option called 'events':

```
add_filter("product_type_options", function ($product_type_options) {
  $product_type_options['event'] = array(
        'id'            => '_event',
        'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple show_if_variable',
        'label'         => __( 'Wydarzenie', 'behold-basic' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Wydarzenie', 'behold-basic' ),
        'default'       => 'no'
    );
    return $product_type_options;
});

add_action("save_post_product", function ($post_ID, $product, $update) {
  update_post_meta(
        $product->ID
      , "_event"
      , isset($_POST["_event"]) ? "yes" : "no"
  );
}, 10, 3);
```

I want to use it in 'simple' and 'variable' products to mark them as my events. But now I need to check if this option is checked, just like `is_virtual`, because it's the same option type. How should I do that in best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do like `$product->is_virtual()` without changing or extending `WC_Product`.
I won't suggest taking that route if you have limited time.

Your best bet is to use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: Thank U! This is what I need :)